# Application path in General class (.CS)

Tags: c#

Hi i want to get applcation path in one seperate class used in my XAML,WPF applcation.
In Animals.cs,

```
string aPath2 = Application.StartupPath;
 MessageBox.Show(path);
```

It shws error
***error CS0117: 'System.Windows.Application' does not contain a definition for 'StartupPath'***

I have to give data to treeview,im taking that all details from file in applcation path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [**AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx)

StartupPath was only for Windows forms

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`, which will return the full path to the assembly that contains the currently executing method.  The result will be independent of any working directory settings.

Answer (score 2):

You could use add the following to the top:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

then Application.StartupPath should work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code too

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

the Environment  inherited from System.